# Why FYI is called slang word?

Tags: expressions

> FYI is "For Your Information"

But it is considered as a slang word: http://www.internetslang.com/FYI-meaning-definition.asp why?

Comment: You should not be gullible to allow any Paul, Pete or Mary who sets up a web site, dictate to you that a broom is a spade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it accepts a seemingly false premise (that FYI is slang) and then seeks an explanation/justification of that premise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called *internet slang*, which is means that is is considered to be part of the specific way language is used on the internet.

It is also an acronym, and it can also be used outside the internet.

The fact that is is included in list of words and expressions that are considered *internet slang* does not mean the specific acronym is a slang word only.

Also, just because somebody makes a website and calls it *internet slang* does not mean that every word he lists all of a sudden change their function in the English language.

I can make a list of all words starting with *A*, and include the word *apple*, but that does not mean that the word *apple* from that moment on no longer is a noun, or that it no longer can be a slang word (as in Big Apple), or that no body has the right to verb the noun (stop appling! - whatever that means).

Simply said, *FYI* can be considered internet slang, because it is used on the internet in internet-specific communication styles.

Comment: If FYI is part of 'internet slang' so were the ancient Romans. I used FYI decades before the internet was born.

Comment: The reason for inclusion in such a list is simply that someone looking up unknown acronyms found in say, a chat conversation, is likely to not know which ones out of _TTYL, LOL, FYI, AFK, BRB_ existed pre-internet. But indeed, inclusion in the list does not make it slang. It only means it is included on the named site.

Comment: @WS2 - In ancient Rome, FYI was Fiscal Year I, (followed by FYII and FYIII). ;^)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't necessarily call *FYI* internet slang, and InternetSlang.com don't necessarily claim it is slang:

> The slang word / acronym / abbreviation FYI

Despite the name, InternetSlang.com doesn't differentiate between the three categories and the site isn't really authoritative or definitive. It seems they're just trying to harvest Google hits to earn money from advertising. You can tell this partly from the vague text on the page:

> **What does FYI mean?**
>
> This could be the only web page dedicated to explaining the meaning of FYI (FYI acronym/abbreviation/slang word).

It's definitely not.

> Ever wondered what FYI means? Or any of the other 9062 slang words, abbreviations and acronyms listed here at Internet Slang? Your resource for web acronyms, web abbreviations and netspeak.
>
> **What is FYI?**
>
> FYI is "For Your Information"
>
> **FYI Definition / FYI Means**
>
> The definition of FYI is "For Your Information"
>
> **The Meaning of FYI**
>
> FYI means "For Your Information"
>
> So now you know - FYI means "For Your Information" - don't thank us. YW!
>
> What does FYI mean? FYI is an acronym, abbreviation or slang word that is explained above where the FYI definition is given.

Most of this is filler and the same definition repeated three times to match different search terms.

I'd categorise *FYI* as an abbreviation and jargon rather than slang and suggest using any of the dictionaries at [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/) and avoid InternetSlang.com.